# ATK4 Fatal Error atk4\core\Exception: Attempting to initialize twice

Tags: php, atk4

I am exploring the Atk4 UI. Below I am tried to use a View with several Table views (with array data), but the atk4 shows fatal error: `Attempting to initialize twice`.

```
$mainDiv = new \atk4\ui\View();
$table = new \atk4\ui\Table(['celled' => true]);
$table->setSource([['test'=>5]]);
$mainDiv->add($table);
$app->layout->add($mainDiv);
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Trying your example as-is I got this error:

> atk4\ui\Exception\NoRenderTree: You must use either add($obj) or $obj->init() before addColumn()

After adding `$table->init()` right before `setSource()` made example work. However for table to work you need to define columns.

Comment: Also you should try to use latest possible version of Atk4 UI.